# SyntaxError when using cx_freeze on PyQt app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, cx-freeze

This is quite annoying problem that occurs when trying to build .exe file from Python 3 script using PyQt4. I think it is connected with using `uic` module for dynamic loading of `.ui` files.
`cx_freeze` returns:

```
  File "E:\Python32_32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 366, in _LoadModule
    module.code = compile(codeString, path, "exec")
  File "E:\Python32_32\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\port_v2\load_plugin.py", line 41
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have solved this problem some time ago but I have recently encountered it again. Finding solution on the web isn't easy so I decided to post Q&A on SO. Hope it will be helpful not only for me :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem lies in fact that `cx_freeze` tries to use `uic` submodule for Python 2, not 3 and encounters Py3-incompatible syntax in one of files. Solution is quite simple:

Find `uic` directory, it should  be located in `your_python_dir\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic`. There are two directories there: `port_v2` and `port_v3`. Rename the first one, for example to `port_v2_`. I think similar problem can occur while using Python2-rename `v3` then. Anyway, this will cause `cx_freeze` to find proper version of `uic` and the script should build correctly.